# Mongoid query for embeds_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, mongoid4

Following query is running in MongoDB console correctly,

```
> db.venues.find({'location.region_id':ObjectId("533e67246d696e1279170000")}).count()
8
```

But when i write the same query in rails using mongoid its not showing anything, the query is as follows,

```
<%= Venue.where({'location.region_id' => '533e67246d696e1279170000'}).count %>
```

I don't know what's wrong with my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the id to an `ObjectId` object:

```
<%= Venue.where({'location.region_id' => BSON::ObjectId.from_string('533e67246d696e1279170000')}).count %>
```